How to set up indexing for JanusGraph+Solr using C#?
I'm currently using Gremlin.Net to add data, read data, and perform analysis on JanusGraph. When it comes to operations like 'traversing all edges of a vertex and checking if all connected vertices are the same,' the performance is unbearably slow. Therefore, I switched from the default inmemory database to JanusGraph+Cassandra+Solr.
However, the existing example code is mostly in Java, so I'm looking for a way to create indexes in C#."
The known example code is as follows:https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/solr/
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
age = mgmt.makePropertyKey("age").dataType(Integer.class).make()
mgmt.buildIndex("verticesByAge", Vertex.class).addKey(age).buildMixedIndex("search")
mgmt.commit()

